# In an Android XML layout, can I use a child view or viewgroup to tint part of the parent's background?

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently have the following layout as part of my XML file:

```
LinearLayout (orientation: vertical)
+---TextView (title)
+---LinearLayout (orientation: horizontal)
    +---ConstraintLayout
        +---...
    +---ConstraintLayout
        +---...
    +---ConstraintLayout
        +---...
```

The parent `LinearLayout` has a background that is a drawable.

My intention is to have the child `TextView` and child `LinearLayout` tint a part of said parent `LinearLayout`'s background each with different colors.

I've tried the `backgroundTint` and `foregroundTint` attributes in both the child layouts, but neither changed the parent `LinearLayout`'s drawable in any way.

So, is there any way I can do what I asked in the title, or am I stuck subclassing the `LinearLayout` and overriding the `onDraw` function?

Comment: You could set their `background`s to a translucent color.

Comment: set padding to child views and set background to child views.... parent view's bg won't change as desired ...

Comment: @MikeM. That complicates things if the parent background has transparency layers.

Comment: In that case, you're not going to be able to do this strictly in layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, I'm stuck with using the `ViewGroup`'s `onDraw` function:

```
public class PartialTintedRoundedRectLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    Context ctx;
    RectF topPartitionRect, botPartitionRect;
    RectF topBandAidRect, botBandAidRect;
    Paint bgTopPaint, bgBotPaint;

    int defaultCornerRadius;
    float material30sdp;

    public PartialTintedRoundedRectLinearLayout(Context c) {
        super(c);
        init(c);
    }

    public PartialTintedRoundedRectLinearLayout(Context c, AttributeSet a) {
        super(c, a);
        init(c);
    }

    public PartialTintedRoundedRectLinearLayout(Context c, AttributeSet a, int dsAttr) {
        super(c, a, dsAttr);
        init(c);
    }

    private void init(Context c) {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        ctx = c;
        defaultCornerRadius = (int)(20 * ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        material30sdp = ctx.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._30sdp);
        bgTopPaint = new Paint(); bgTopPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.blue_700));
        bgBotPaint = new Paint(); bgBotPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.blue_500));
        getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                topPartitionRect = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), material30sdp);
                topBandAidRect = new RectF(0, defaultCornerRadius, getWidth(), material30sdp);
                botPartitionRect = new RectF(0, material30sdp, getWidth(), getHeight());
                botBandAidRect = new RectF(0, material30sdp, getWidth(), getHeight() - defaultCornerRadius);
                invalidate();
                getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(topPartitionRect, defaultCornerRadius, defaultCornerRadius, bgTopPaint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(botPartitionRect, defaultCornerRadius, defaultCornerRadius, bgBotPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(topBandAidRect, bgTopPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(botBandAidRect, bgBotPaint);
    }
}
```

I'll have to figure out how to make it more general, since this was made for one specific use-case.

Comment: see `layout / onLayout` methods

Comment: I've seen it. The compiler complains about not being recommended to initialize `Rect`s in the view's `onLayout` method, however.

Comment: who said you should initialize them inside `onLayout` method? use `Rect#set` and initialize them to the empty rect in the ctor